# Random Script Errors on CRM 2016 Forms

Tags: javascript, customization, dynamics-crm-2016

Some random script error messages have started to occur since when we upgraded from CRM 2011 to CRM 2016,
mainly on form Load. I tried including all dependency scripts on form properties properly but still no luck. I have gone through very good article [CRM 2013 Script Loading Deep Dive](http://develop1.net/public/post/CRM-2013-Script-Loading-Deep-Dive.aspx) shared by Scott Durow. After implementing the workaround it is showing a script error. I don't want to switch to legacy form rendering. Please suggest something I can implement. Some of Script errors in the log are:

```
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'ParentProduct' of undefined
at eval (eval at RunHandlerInternal (192.168.220.55/.../ClientApiWrapper.aspx), <anonymous>:1:13)**

at RunHandlerInternal (192.168.220.55/.../ClientApiWrapper.aspx)
at RunHandlers (192.168.220.55/.../ClientApiWrapper.aspx)
at OnScriptTagLoaded (192.168.220.55/.../ClientApiWrapper.aspx)
at http://192.168.220.55/Dev/form/ClientApiWrapper.aspx?ver=191855143:201:1

**TypeError: Unable to get property 'executeOnLoad' of undefined or null reference
at eval code (eval code:1:1)**

at RunHandlerInternal (192.168.220.55/.../ClientApiWrapper.aspx)
at RunHandlers (192.168.220.55/.../ClientApiWrapper.aspx)
at OnScriptTagLoaded (192.168.220.55/.../ClientApiWrapper.aspx)
at Anonymous function (192.168.220.55/.../ClientApiWrapper.aspx)
```

Script Executing onLoad is:

```
   Sonoma.namespace("Utilities").namespace("ParentProduct").extend((function () {
        function func1() {
        }
        function func2() {
        }
        )());
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you contacted Sonoma to report errors related to their code? With this namespace, I have to assume they are the authors. http://www.sonomapartners.com/

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the timing of the script load - I suspect the Sonoma.namespace("Utilities") is defined in another script file that may not have been loaded yet.